# How to send Javascript Blob to SingleR hub?

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-service

I added a javascript page that would allow the user to record voice using their microphone.

I want to send the recording to a [SignalR hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Here is the javascript code that does the recording and then when the `sendButton` is called, the byte array is send to the signalR hub using the `upload` function.

```js
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hub").build();

let audioRecorder;
let data = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {

        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        audioRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => {
            data.push(e.data);
        });

        startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            audioRecorder.start();
        });

        stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            audioRecorder.stop();
        });

        sendButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {

            const blobObj = new Blob(data, { type: 'audio/webm' });

            var bytes = await blobObj.arrayBuffer();

            const subject = new signalR.Subject();
            subject.next(bytes)
            connection.invoke('upload', 'filename', subject);
            subject.complete();
        });
    })
```

I added this code in the

```cs
public partial class MyHub : Hub<IMyHub>
{
    public async Task Upload(string filename, IAsyncEnumerable<byte> stream)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        await foreach (var item in stream)
        {
            memoryStream.WriteByte(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Upload` method gets hit as expected, but the `stream` parameter has no data.

How can I upload the recording byte array to the SignalR hub?

Comment: Be more specific. `IAsyncEnumerable` doesn't have a `Current` property. The underlying `Enumerator` will also not have a value for `Current` until you start iterating over the enumerator.
Also, using streaming to send a single `byte[]` doesn't give you anything. You could just send the `byte[]`.

Comment: @Brennan thank you! I updated the OP to show the last code I tried which accepts `IAsyncEnumerable<byte>`. the stream has no data.

Comment: Hi  Jay, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brennan, but SignalR itself does not directly support sending byte arrays as individual parameters. You might consider converting the byte array to a `Base64 string` and then converting it back to a byte stream on the server side.

Here is the sample code for you.

```
sendButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const blobObj = new Blob(data, { type: 'audio/webm' });

    var arrayBuffer = await blobObj.arrayBuffer();
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...bytes));

    // Send Base64 string directly
    connection.invoke('Upload', 'filename', base64String);
});
```

*Backend code*

```
public async Task Upload(string filename, string base64Data)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

    //According to your needs
    //var filePath = Path.Combine("Your_Destination_folder_Path", filename);
    //await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, bytes);
}
```